# IEnumerable items to be added to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, namevaluecollection

I have a class:

```
 public class CustomerItem
    {
        public CustomerItem(IEnumerable<SomeProperty> someProperties, 
                        IEnumerable<Grade> grades, 
                        decimal unitPrice, int quantity, string productCode)
        {
            SomeProperties = someProperties;
            Grades = grades;
            UnitPrice = unitPrice;
            Quantity = quantity;
            ProductCode = productCode;
        }


        public string ProductCode { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SomeProperty> SomeProperties { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I have a:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerItem> CustomerItems {get; set;}
```

and I am able to get the `CustomerItems` populated with relevant data.

Now, I would like to add all the items from `CustomerItems` to a `NameValueCollection`.

```
NameValueCollection target = new NameValueCollection();
     // I want to achieve 
     target.Add(x,y); // For all the items in CustomerItems
    // where - x - is of the format - Line1 -  for first item  like "Line" + i
    // "Line" is just a hardcodedvalue to be appended  
    // with the respective item number in the iteration.
    // where - y - is the concatenation of all the values for that specific line.
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: In your code you did mention "line" only in comments. What's that? BTW what's wrong with a foreach?

Comment: @Adriano  "Line" is a hardcodevalue that I need to appear in the key appended with the number of each iteration in Ienumerable.

Comment: And what's the concationation of items in that line? A subset of CustomerItems? All CustomerItems?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define how all the values in `CustomerItem` should be concatenated. One way would be to override `ToString` in `CustomerItem`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // define the concatenation as you see fit
    return String.Format("{0}: {1} x {2}", ProductCode, Quantity, UnitPrice);
}
```

Now you can fill in the target `NameValueCollection` by simply iterating over `CustomerItems`:

```
var index = 1;
var target = new NameValueCollection();
foreach (var customerItem in CustomerItems)
{
    target.Add(String.Format("Line {0}", i), customerItem.ToString());
    i++;
}
```

If you replace `NameValueCollection` with a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you can do it even by just using LINQ:

```
var target = CustomerItems.Select((item, index) => new 
                              { 
                                  Line = String.Format("Line {0}", index + 1), 
                                  Item = item.ToString()
                              })
                          .ToDictionary(i => i.Line, i => i.Item);
```